Density of a multivariate degenerate distribution?
Is there a way to write down the density of a multivariate degenerate distribution?
The simplest example I can think is the case where we have any continuous variable $X$, and $Y = X$.
Clearly the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ is degenerate, because $P(X \ne Y) = 0$.
We can still write the multivariate cumulative distribution as
$F_{X,Y}(x,y) = P(X \le x, Y \le x) = F_X(  \min(x,y))$
However, we can't write
$f_{X,Y}(x, y) = f_X(x) I[{x = y]}$
as this "density" integrates to 0 over $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Lebesgue measure $\mathcal{L}^2$.
However, is it still possible to write down a probability measure for $X$ and $Y$?

Degenerate distributions do not have a density.

@geetha290krm Not a density with respect to the Lebesgue measure but with respect to another dominating measure ν.

Density depends on the measure. With respect to the measure induced by $(X,Y)$ the density is just the constant $1$.

There is a 'Lebesgue measure' on the line ${(x,y):x=y}$ and you can compute the density w.r.t. this measure also.

@geetha290krm what would be the notation for that?

In the example given where $X = Y$, we can define the probability measure as
\begin{align}\mu_{X,Y}(A) &= \mu_X(\{x : (x, x) ∈ A\}) \\
                          &= \int_{\{x : (x, x) ∈ A\}} f(x) d\lambda(x)\\
                          &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} I[(x,x) \in A]f(x) d\lambda(x) \\
&= \int^\infty_{-\infty} I[(x,x) \in A]f(x) dx
\end{align}
where $f(x)$ is the density of $X$ and $\lambda(x)$ is the usual Lesbesgue measure on the real line.
That is, we integrate over one dimension over $x$ for which $(x,  y) \in A$, with $x = y$.
